# Python file encrypting

Tags: python, file, encryption, encoding, file-encodings

I am trying to write a program that will encrypt a file by using the `.read()` function on the file content, which returns `98\xf1\xc6}xb1\*`.... I am trying to encrypt the file by looping through each character an incrementing its decimal number by 1 (numbers range from 0 -> 255). and then adding each incremented number to a new list.

new list looks something like this:

`['«', 'û', '$', '\x00', 'Ú']`...

How do i convert this new list into a format which can be written in binary mode?

```
class Encrypting():

    def __init__(self):
        self.file = "files/test_img.jpg" 


    def open_file(self):
        f = open(self.file, "rb")
        self.content = f.read()
        print(self.content)
        f.close()


    def convert_file_data(self):
        self.new_values = []
        for i in self.content:
            new_val = i + 1
            if i == 255:
                new_val = 0
            new_val = chr(new_val)
            self.new_values.append(new_val)


    def rewrite(self):          
        f = open("files/conv1.jpg", "wb")
        f.write(self.new_values)
        f.close()


def main():
    encrypt = Encrypting()
    encrypt.open_file()
    encrypt.convert_file_data()
    encrypt.rewrite()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Comment: Why are u trying to convert the new_val into a char? This line: new_val = chr(new_val)

Comment: i was trying to see if self.new_values could be written to a new file through binary mode, when given a list of ascii chars. Just trying different things

Comment: new_values should be a bytearray and not list, also remove that line and should work

Comment: `if i == 255` should also be `== 256`, since you're incrementing before you check the value. However, there is no need for the if-statement; you can do `new_val = (i + 1) % 256` to achieve the same effect.

Comment: @MatsLindh i never gets incremented (?). Confusing with new_val or I'm missing something? It is confusing and i should be a b since its not an index

Comment: @MatsLindh: `new_val` will only be `256` when `i` is `255`, so the test is correct, if a little confusing.

Comment: Oh, my bad. That was confusing, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* change:

```
f.write(self.new_values)
```

to:

```
f.write(''.join(self.new_values).encode('latin-1'))
```

combining the `list` of `str` into a single `str`, then encoding it to `latin-1` (which is the 1-1 mapping of the first 256 Unicode ordinals to bytes of the same values).

But the real solution is to change:

```
def convert_file_data(self):
    self.new_values = []
    for i in self.content:
        new_val = i + 1
        if i == 255:
            new_val = 0
        new_val = chr(new_val)
        self.new_values.append(new_val)
```

to:

```
def convert_file_data(self):
    self.new_values = bytearray()  # A mutable sequence of bytes, ints in range(256), so no type conversions needed
    for i in self.content:
        new_val = i + 1
        if i == 255:
            new_val = 0
        # chr conversion is unnecessary and counter-productive, so we just append the new byte
        self.new_values.append(new_val)
```

This part:

```
        new_val = i + 1
        if i == 255:
            new_val = 0
```

could be simplified to:

```
        new_val = (i + 1) % 256
```

as well, which could then simplify the whole function to:

```
def convert_file_data(self):
    self.new_values = bytearray()  # A mutable sequence of bytes, ints in range(256), so no type conversions needed
    for i in self.content:
        self.new_values.append((i + 1) % 256)
```

or even shorter, a simple genexpr fed to the `bytes`/`bytearray` constructor:

```
def convert_file_data(self):
    self.new_values = bytes((i + 1) % 256 for i in self.content)
```

Any of the `bytes` or `bytearray` based solutions are superior to storing a `list` of `str` in that:

1. They require far less memory (the length one `str`s are likely cached, but the pointers to them stored in the `list` require 4-8 bytes a piece, vs. just one byte a piece for the raw `bytes`)
2. It's less CPU intensive (appending individual bytes is cheaper, and there's no additional costs at the end to re`join` and `encode` the data, it's already in the correct form natively)